# taxonomy_get_tree return only few terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms

i have a problem with `taxonomy_get_tree()`.

I want to get all tags from taxonomy. Tags's vocabulary ID (vid) is 1. When I check this in database there are about 4000 terms. If I use `taxonomy_get_tree(1)` it returns only 150 terms.

Do anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for every advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem was caused by wrong migration from drupal 6 site to drupal 7. Some connection were missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your code:  `taxonomy_get_tree(1,0,NULL,TRUE)`

Syntax:

```
taxonomy_get_tree($vid, $parent = 0, $max_depth = NULL, $load_entities = FALSE)
```

> Parameters
>
> **$vid:** Which vocabulary to generate the tree for.
>
> **$parent:** The term ID under which to generate the tree. If 0, generate
>   the tree for the entire vocabulary.
>
> **$max_depth:** The number of levels of the tree to return. Leave NULL to
>   return all levels.
>
> **$load_entities:** If TRUE, a full entity load will occur on the term
>   objects. Otherwise they are partial objects queried directly from the
>   {taxonomy_term_data} table to save execution time and memory
>   consumption when listing large numbers of terms. Defaults to FALSE.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, result is still same.